# How can I make my plot continuous?

Tags: plotting

Looks like plots became of low quality in Mathematica 9?

[image]

How to make *Mathematica* to plot continuously? Logically current plot style is solid.

Comment: Looks fine for me, 9.0.1 on Windows.

Comment: You can remove the gaps by adding `Exclusions -> None` so it will be a continuous stairs like plot

Comment: Please post the actual code (as text) in addition to the picture.

Comment: The CDF of a binomial distribution is not a continuous function.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, your plot rendered fine as per my comments, and more interestingly, as soon as I added an `Export` after the fact, the plot looked like yours. This persisted even after removing the export and re-plotting: I had to quit the kernel, restart, and re-plot. Might be a weird bug, I will be investigating further.

In any case, `DiscretePlot` is really better suited to the CDF of a discrete distribution:

```
DiscretePlot[CDF[BinomialDistribution[1001, 1/2], x], {x, 0, 1001}, 
             PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True]
```

[image]